# Tracking field personnal using android app and showing in ArcGISonline

Tags: arcgis-server, android, arcgis-online, arcgis-android

Planning to equip field personnel with GPS enabled phones (android) and collect the location and photograph of assets.

Can we use ArcGIS for android in the phone, use this to upload GPS and photos , and the use ArcGIS online to show these locations ?

Do we need ArcGIS for server or simple we can do it using ArcGISOnline and android SDK ?

Adarsh

Comment: Do you want to track these personnel in real time? Are they going to collect some data?

Comment: Hi devdatta , I need to track them as well as collect the data in the sense, just locations and photographs.No mapping is required.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the "Collector for Android" app - http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2013/01/16/operations-dashboard-and-collector-for-arcgis-released/

Or write your own application using the ArcGIS Runtime SDK for Android - http://resources.arcgis.com/en/communities/runtime-android/

In either case, you wouldn't need ArcGIS for Server, but could instead use an ArcGIS Online organizational account - http://www.esri.com/software/arcgis/arcgisonline